# custom views before modal transition animation

Tags: ios, animation, storyboard, customization, uistoryboardsegue

I have one problem that I can't understand. I know that viewDidLoad method call when the .xib is loaded, in this moment you can customize your IBOutlet object. Well my problem consist that modal flipboard transition between two views show de destination view without any customization, when this animation finish the view show correctly.

I do few manys customization (custom font in label and set background color in any views) in viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self setupTimeViews];
    [self setupDistanceViews];

    [self animationToColor:[UIColor randomColor] animated:NO];
}
```

How I customize my IBOutlets before that animation start?

UPDATE:

I see that the problem happen when I try to round the views corners

Answer (score 0):

The viewDidLoad method is called only after the view is loaded into the memory and this some times can be very late to perform UI customization.

Try doing your UI customization in `-(void)awakeFromNib` this method is called once the nib is unarchived and all outlets are wired up. It is the safest place to modify UI components.

From apple documentation

> An **awakeFromNib** message is sent to each object loaded from the
>   archive, but only if it can respond to the message, and only after all
>   the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an
>   object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all
>   its outlet instance variables set.

Comment: Thanks I am trying this to improve the performance. Finally the problem was the simulator, in a device work fine :). Thanks!